# CSS jumping focus

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with links for which their focus is jumping around.

The site is here: [www.bikramyoga.cz](http://www.bikramyoga.cz)

The links that are troublesome are in this HTML piece:

```
<ul id="sub">
    <li id="mail">
        <a href="posta.htm" title="chci zasílat novinky">chci zasílat novinky</a>
    </li>
    <li id="fb_icon">
        <a href="http://www.facebook.com/BikramYogaPrague?sk=wall" target="_blank">to se mi líbí</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I first created the site the links worked fine, now not so much.
Any ideas where my CSS is messed up?

Comment: In which browser and what did you mean by "jumping around"?

Comment: Need more clarification. What are the links meant to be doing?

Comment: when the user mouses over the focus moves, and there should be an underline under the icons during mouseover. The underline ends up being over to the right instead

Comment: Only Firefox, all others work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you display your `<a>` as `block`, instead of `inline-block` it seems to work as you want.

```
#mail a{display:block}
#fb_icon a{display:block}
```